How to get the cvc5 partition results and run cvc5 in parallel?
I am trying to use the SMT solver cvc5, with the option --compute-partitions to split the original problem and solve.
From this post : https://cvc5.github.io/blog/2023/12/15/partitioning-strategies-for-distributed-smt-solving.html , which says when the cvc5 emits partitions and returns unsat, each partition needs to be appeneded to the original problem and proved again.
cvc5 will print the partitions, but is there any API of cvc5 to get the partitions?
And is there any example of doing this and append the partitions to the original problem?
cvc5cvc4smt
